# When using `scale_x_log10`, how can I map `geom_text` accurately to `geom_bin2d`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

A great answer on how to label the count on `geom_bin2d`, can be found here:

[Getting counts on bins in a heat map using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771018/getting-counts-on-bins-in-a-heat-map-using-r?lq=1)

However, when modifying this to have a logarithmic X axis:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000))

# plot MODIFIED HERE TO BECOME log10
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_bin2d() + scale_x_log10()

# Get data - this includes counts and x,y coordinates 
newdat <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]

# add in text labels
p + geom_text(data=newdat, aes((xmin + xmax)/2, (ymin + ymax)/2, 
                               label=count), col="white")
```

This produces labels that are very poorly mapped to their respective points.

How can I correct the `geom_text` based labels to correctly map to thier respective points?

Comment: Square tiles won't be square anymore in log axis, isn't it misleading for your plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply logarithmic transformation directly on x values, not on scale. Change only one line of your code:

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = log10(x), y = y)) + geom_bin2d()
```

That allows to keep negative values and produces the following plot:
[image]